# regex extract multiple lines containing exception stacktrace

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, regex-group

What is the correct Regex to extract multiple lines error with exception strack trace from a log file. Here is my Example.

```
Verbose;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:48,831;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Repository CareProviderRepository:START GetCareProviderByZsrMethod with ZSR: H110702
Error;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:51,409;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Repository CareProviderRepository:Fail to get CareProviderMethod with Zsrnumber: H110702
Error;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:51,933;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Services:Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Name_DE'.
Invalid column name 'Name_FR'.
Invalid column name 'Name_IT'.
Invalid column name 'DefaultText'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
Verbose;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:52,361;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Business NetworkManager:START Get: Network with Code: 95; withNetworkMembers: False
Verbose;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:52,369;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Repository NetworkRepository:START Get: 95
Error;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:51,933;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Services:Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Name_DE'.
Invalid column name 'Name_FR'.
Invalid column name 'Name_IT'.
Invalid column name 'DefaultText'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
Verbose;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:52,361;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Business NetworkManager:START Get: Network with Code: 95; withNetworkMembers: False
Verbose;MyComputer;07.02.2017 12:42:52,369;Area=;SubArea=;SessionId=;StepId;User=;Message=Repository NetworkRepository:START Get: 95
```

Here is my RegEx: `(Error;(?:.*\r?\n?)\s)`

This regex only select me one line or error. Actually i want a regex which can select me 3 Error (first error is Singleline and later 2 errors are Multiline).

My regex is not escaping CRLF or Newline at the end of Error Line.

The trailing boundaries for each record are either `Debug;`, `Verbose;`, `Info;` or `Error;`.

Any suggesions ?

Comment: Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/ppKM8P/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in this particular example, it can be possible to differentiate `Error`s on `Verbose`s: https://regex101.com/r/d67ua5/1

Comment: the question is: which lines really belong tot the error? Wiktor suggested to extract everything till the next 'Error'. Is it correct?

Comment: @BrightOne Yeah, although the [`;` should be after `Error`](https://regex101.com/r/Jg6Ojk/1), too. Sounds rather unclear to me anyway.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect solution. Its working for me. it should start extracting from word "Error;" and end before next occurrence of words like "Error;|Verbose;|Info;|Debug;" etc Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex

```
/^Error;.*(?:\r?\n(?!Error;|Verbose;|Info;|Debug;).*)*/gm
```

Please adapt the notation to the language you are using.

**Details**

- `^  - start of a line (`m`modifier makes the`^` match the start of a line rather than the whole string)
- `Error;` - matches a literal substring `Error;`
- `.*` -  matches the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Error;|Verbose;|Info;|Debug;).*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `\r?\n(?!Error;|Verbose;|Info;|Debug;)` - a line break not followed with any of the alternatives inside parentheses
  - `.*` - the whole line.